# What is the correct way to see what signals a process handles?

Tags: process, proc, signal

EDIT: Since my question was not clear let me reformulate: how can one find what signals a process handles? From this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to

It seems that this will provide such information:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/status
```

under SigCgt.

In this case why do if I run:

```
sleep 1d &
[1] 203027
cat /proc/203027/status
```

I get

```
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
```

Which in my understanding means that no signals are handled by the process.

However

```
kill -SIGTERM 203027
```

effectively kills the sleep process?
From the "status" file it looks as though sleep isn't handling any signals. What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you hear that? I strongly suggest you hear things from somewhere else in the future.

Comment: I do not see a question here. Just some where the heck did he get this info.

Comment: Edited. Now do you see the question? I also posted the source of the information I was mentioning.

Comment: The OP of that question didn't know what they were asking either, but the accepted answer explicitly says signals are blocked, ignored or handled. That is: signals or not something you listen for.

Comment: I mean. Ok. It's important to use the right wording. I edited my question and replaced wherever I say "listen" to "handle" instead.  I guess it wasn't clear enough. BTW the answer says that signals are blocked, ignored or CAUGHT.

Comment: In this case it is very much important: a signal which is not ignored or blocked is (eventually) delivered; a delivered signal which is not handled (usually) kills the process (depending on the signal "disposition"). (I use "handled" instead of "caught" because a process installs signal "handlers" for caught signals.) Most of this is explained in detail in [`man 7 signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).